# Laravel insertGetId insert multiple rows and get inserted primary keys

Tags: mysql, laravel, database, laravel-8

The problem I am facing in the api is as follows: it is not accepting array of multiple arrays:

```bash
...
"message": "Array to string conversion",
"exception": "ErrorException",
"file": "/home/deepan8/pich.abc.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Str.php",
"line": 762,
"trace": [
    {
    "file": "/home/deepan8/pich.abc.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/HandleExceptions.php",
    "line": 257,
    "function": "handleError",
    "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions",
    "type": "->"
    },]
```

My code snippet looks like this:

```php
$voucherArray = [];
foreach($users as $user) {
    $voucherArray[] = ['voucher_code' => rand(10000, 999999),
        'voucher_price' => $request->price,
        'expiry_date' => $request->date,
        'status' => "Active",
    ];
}
$ids = DB::table('pich_voucher')->insertGetId($voucherArray);
foreach($ids as $id) {

}
```

I need to add all the rows at once instead of adding them one by one to improve performance.
Does Laravel have some function which can provide this facility or any SQL Query where we can add multiple rows and extract their ids at the same time?

Comment: Please paste your code, not just screenshot.

Comment: Raw MySQL lets you insert multiple rows at once.  A CSV also works, but you would have to construct it.  Some other frameworks have something like "executemany".

Answer (score 1):

You can insert multiple rows using `insertGetId()` method. If you want really want to insert multiple rows and get the IDs, just use looping.

example:

```
    $ids = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $voucherArray = array(
            'voucher_code' => rand(10000, 999999),
            'voucher_price' => $request->price,
            'expiry_date' => $request->date,
            'status' => "Active"
        );
        $ids[] = DB::table('pich_voucher')->insertGetId($voucherArray);
    }
```

Or another way use [insert](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#insert-statements) method but not get the ids. if you want to get the ids you could use like below:

```
    $voucherArray = [];
    $codes = [];
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $code= rand(10000, 999999);
        $codes[] = $code;
        $voucherArray[] = array(
            'voucher_code' => $code,
            'voucher_price' => $request->price,
            'expiry_date' => $request->date,
            'status' => "Active"
        );
    }
    DB::table('pich_voucher')->insert($voucherArray);
    $ids = DB::table('pich_voucher')->whereIn('voucher_code', $codes)->pluck('id')->toArray();
```

Comment: but the problem is i don't want to put the query in the loop i just want to add multiple rows at once cause opening and closing db document for query will cost lots of time and energy it will gonna effect when when there are more user records lets say more then 600 records.

Comment: @JunaidAli I already give you the possible solutions. In Laravel, we can not do that with built-in function and in the most of databases, there is no way  to get IDs from bulk insert.  
the second choice is cheapest and use low energy..